# Removing plus sign from the query string php

Tags: php, javascript, regex, preg-match

When user input space or nothing in the input bar, a plus sign + is still passed to my php backend. I would want to remove all  plus signs before and after a word (e.g. return 'school' from '+++school++"). I see php have some nice function like strip_tag, but I am not sure what I should use in this case. Or is there a way to configure it (maybe through javascript?) so that those meaningless space/+ wouldn't even enter into the query string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$input = trim(urldecode($input));
```

where $input is one of the post parameters, such as: `$input = $_POST["query"];` // if query was the POST parameter.

Edit: The other advantage of using urldecode is that it takes care of all other non alphanumeric characters that have been encoded.

From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer. Although you probably want `trim(urldecode($input))` to remove excess spaces.

Comment: **-1** The query string comes through in  `$_GET`, which already handles url decoding.

Comment: @Eric That's how it should be accessed, but it seems whatever the OP is doing to get the query string isn't decoding things.

Comment: @Eric, what makes you think OP is using GET to begin with?

Comment: @ajacian81: "query string". [From wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) - _'Technically, the form content is only encoded as a query string when the form submission method is GET.'_

Answer (score 0):

The `+` in the query string becomes a space in `$_GET`. All you need to do is trim leading and trailing spaces.

```
trim($_GET['param'])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = '++school++';
return trim(urldecode($str)
```

Comment: @ajacian81 OP want to remove all `+` from his input, urldecode if im not mistaken simple decode it to space..obviously cluterred OP input